# Optimize javascript of custom controls

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web, custom-controls

Is there a way to group the javascript of the custom controls which has same settings?

Exemple:

I put 3 of my custom controls on a page. Each one write a javascript like

```
ucx.initialize( controlID, settings );
```

So I get...

```
ucx.initialize("txtValue1", { sync: true, mask: '0 km' });
ucx.initialize("txtValue2", { sync: true, mask: '0 km' });
ucx.initialize("txtValue3", { sync: true, mask: '0 mm'});
```

As we can see, the "txtValue1" and "txtValue2" has the same settings.

So I would like to group them:

```
ucx.initialize(["txtValue1", "txtValue2"], { sync: true, mask: '0 km'});
ucx.initialize("txtValue3", { sync: true, mask: '0 mm'});
```

It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on what your `initialize` function does.

At the least, you could use a defaulted common settings object:

```
var initialize = function (controlID, settings) { 
    ...
    settings = settings || { sync: true, mask: '0 km'};
    ... 
};
```

Then, if you call the function without passing a settings object, it is defaulted to the common one:

```
ucx.initialize("txtValue1");
ucx.initialize("txtValue2");
ucx.initialize("txtValue3", { sync: true, mask: '0 mm'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own method that would work similarly:

```
ucx.initializeMultiple = function() {
    var settings = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {
        ucx.initialize(arguments[i], settings);
    }
}
```

Then, you can call:

```
ucx.initializeMultiple("txtValue1", "txtValue2", { sync: true, mask: '0 km'});
```

You can put as many field names in the arguments as you want.  The last argument is the settings object.  All arguments before it are interpreted as field names that should each get that settings.

---

Keep in mind that the settings don't have to be inline.  Without creating this new method, you could also have just done this to avoid repeating the settings:

```
var settings1 = { sync: true, mask: '0 km'};
ucx.initialize("txtValue1", settings1);
ucx.initialize("txtValue2", settings1);
```